# UFT API equivalent for QTP "ExitAction" and/or "ExitIteration"

Tags: hp-uft, uft-api

I really wish HP's API ServiceTest was more friendly. Sorry to keep asking these kinds of questions.

I'm in an activity and want to exit out of it without break the logic up into 2 pieces of code so that I can do an "if/else" to get it out of there. I'm over 200 objects already and managing them during development is a nightmare.

I'm sure(hoping) there is a simple way to call an exit for the activity, but I've tried every single method off the activity.

Thank you!

Comment: BTW - This is from inside a custom code activity. I'm already in a for/each loop above the activity.

Comment: A better alternative would be a way to "call" another activity directly.  (I think I'll post that as a separate question, because both of these have value.)

Comment: It would be better if you post your code.

Comment: Sorry for delay. That's the problem. I don't know what method, etc. to use for the code. In the GUI test side I just enter ExitIteration, or can use ExitGlobaliteration for it to skip to the next Global Iteration.

Comment: I ended up using the "break" activity (drag and dropped) after my execution activity so that I can exit the if/else once I got the condition in there.  I have an if/else "Do While" condition if the APICall contains "correct".  In the "Yes" path, it sends the API Request, does a FileWriteActivity to put the content to a file. I can't find any custom code activity that allows me to exit a parent iteration at that point. I can reset the APICall (which I don't want to do) to end the loop or use a "Continue" activity (which I used). I have 50 loops (200 at the end).